# Где и как указать, что приложение не отслеживает ли ваше приложение контакты с инфицированными или статус COVID-19?

Tags: android, google-play, playmarket

при загрузки приложения в google play, произошла такая ошибка: Вы должны указать, отслеживает ли ваше приложение контакты с инфицированными или статус COVID-19., что делать?

Comment: Может хоть скриншотик? Но скорее всего где-то при загрузке.

Comment: Даже не представляю куда и что, даже если скриншот. Даже нечего не указано, а когда пытаешься его внедрить этот выпуск уже выдает эту ошибку

Comment: Все разобрался, просто в google play, в меню контент приложения, нужно было указать, что мое приложение не отслеживает контакты с инфицированными или статус COVID-19.

Answer (score 4):

в https://play.google.com/console

- перейди в раздел "Контент приложения" (в самом низу)
- в этом разделе, тоже в самом низу, будет пункт "Приложения, отслеживающие контакты - с инфицированными или статус COVID-19"
- нажми начать и выбери то что надо

Answer (score 0):

Если приложение никак не связано с COVID-19, нужно выбрать 3й пункт:

- "Мое приложение не отслеживает контакты с инфицированными или статус COVID-19, оно не общедоступно"

в разделе "Приложения, отслеживающие контакты с инфицированными или статус COVID-19".

Часть предложения "**оно не общедоступно**" вас может ввести в замешательство.
Дело в том, что на русском языке фраза сформулирована не совсем корректно.
На английском данный пункт звучит так:

- "My app is not publicly available COVID-19 contact tracing or status
  app".

Поэтому смело выбираем 3й пункт.